# Why the decode results of different string are same?

Tags: perl

```
$ perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print decode_base64("c3luX2Fja0AxNjMuY29t");'
syn_ack@163.com

$ perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print decode_base64("AHN5bl9hY2tAMTYzLmNvbQ");'
syn_ack@163.com
```

The encode string are different, but the decode results are same, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second string `AHN5bl9hY2tAMTYzLmNvbQ` [decodes to](http://www.base64decode.org/):

```
�syn_ack@163.com
```

The unusual character in first position might not be printed by your terminal software.

Comment: It is a NUL character: `"\0"`.

Comment: http://p3rl.org/uniquote (a replacement for `cat -v`) is useful for detecting/making visible such characters.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what you said, they are not the same:

```
$ perl -MMIME::Base64 -E'
   say
      decode_base64("c3luX2Fja0AxNjMuY29t") eq
      decode_base64("AHN5bl9hY2tAMTYzLmNvbQ") ?1:0'
0
```

So what are they?

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -MMIME::Base64 -e'
   $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
   print Dumper(decode_base64("c3luX2Fja0AxNjMuY29t"))'
$VAR1 = "syn_ack\@163.com";

$ perl -MData::Dumper -MMIME::Base64 -e'
   $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
   print Dumper(decode_base64("AHN5bl9hY2tAMTYzLmNvbQ"))'
$VAR1 = "\0syn_ack\@163.com";
```